# How much damage does the Mind Spike spell do at higher levels?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, errata

*Mind spike*, a 2nd-level spell included in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (p. 162), seems to use different damage dice for the base damage and for additional damage when cast at higher levels.

I have the First Printing of *XGtE*, which has the following text (bold for emphasis mine):

> *2nd-level divination*
>
> […]
>
> You reach into the mind of one creature you can see within range. The target must make a Wisdom saving throw, taking **3d8** psychic damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.
>
> […]
>
> ***At Higher Levels.*** When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 3rd level or higher, the damage increases by **1d6** for each slot level above 2nd.

I have not been able to find any other spells that use different damage dice sizes (d4, d6, d8, etc.) for the damage at the base level and the "At Higher Levels". (The only quasi-exception are spells like *ice storm* that that use multiple different damage dice at the base level for different damage types, but in this case the damage at higher levels uses the same die size as the matching *type* of damage at the base level.) So my suspicion is that this should do base damage of 3d6 ***or*** additional damage of 1d8 for each slot level above 2nd.

Has the *mind spike* spell's damage been errata-ed, corrected in later printings, or is there any other evidence that this is a misprint?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## It was a typo

Prior to this [Crawford confirmed it to be a typo](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/930603935391293440) and the spell entry on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mind-spike) showed 1d8 added per level (as one would expect). With the release of the [2020 Errata to XGtE](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/XGtE-Errata.pdf) *mind spike* was corrected:<sup>1</sup>

> ***Mind Spike (p. 162).*** In the “At Higher Levels” subsection,
> “1d6” has changed to “1d8”.

You may also be interested in [this effort on the Enworld forums](https://www.enworld.org/threads/xgte-errata.598028/) to document the typos and errors in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*.

---

1: I'm not entirely clear on which printings have this correction. The errata document says fourth printings and out have corrections, however it does not appear to be [fixed in the 5th printing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53691294#53691294), which is the latest information available to me.

Answer (score 6):

## It's a mistake

Crawford has confirmed it is supposed to be +1d8/level.

He confirmed it on twitter and it is included in [Sage Advice](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/12/06/is-it-intended-for-mind-spike-to-use-d8s-for-damage-and-then-d6s-when-cast-at-a-higher-level/) (the tweet compendium, not the official errata source).

Comment: It is worth pointing out that that website is simply a collection of developer tweets which is distinct from the official article series published by WotC (on their own website).

Comment: Did he say why it's not in the errata?

Comment: @Mark Is there errata?

Comment: As Someone_Evil points out, a tweet being "included" in a third-party website that compiles pretty much all designer tweets about the game doesn't really mean anything. As such, it's a strange and effectively meaningless thing to note in the answer; you may want to edit that part out. (I'd also have suggested editing it to include a direct link to the tweet instead and possibly quoting the tweet, but it doesn't really say anything that Weaveworker89's answer doesn't already cover...)

Comment: @MarkWells He has in the past. They collect upcoming changes until there are sufficient to significantly update a batch of books rather than change a single book for a couple minor changes. Printing costs money.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, the upscaling is probably in error and should be d8

My primary source is [this tweet by Jeremy Crawford in November 2017](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/930603935391293440), where he was asked the question and answered definitively:

> Mind spike has a typo in its "At Higher Levels" section. It should be "d8," not "d6." That will get corrected.

Based on a thread I found, it appears as though *Xanathar's* has not yet gotten a full errata treatment and so this fix is, in theory, still waiting.